# paste otp in 4 textfields when you copied from email

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

How to automatically paste the one time code which is received in email in react-native text input

otp is sent to email.i have applied multiple solutions but not get any happy ending. when user wanna paste only first field gets filled remaining three otp inputs remain empty
how do i paste copied code in all fields